# SQL: How is it possible to find all data that contain a specific letter in it a specific amount of time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table full of city names and I need to find all the citys that contain the letter "a" at least five times. So far I got:

```
SELECT stadt.Name 
FROM stadt
WHERE stadt.Name LIKE '%a%
```

But this shows me all the citys with an "a". I need to have a code where I am going to get a table with only citys that have 5 x "a" in its name.

Comment: `LIKE '%a%a%a%a%a%'`

Comment: or `LENGTH(stadt.Name) >= LENGTH(REPLACE(stadt.Name, 'a', '') + 5`

Comment: Your question also said, "in a specific amount of time." Do you mean you want this to run faster than doing a table-scan? The solutions presented so far won't do that. They will all take a long time, because the expressions must be evaluated for every row. There's no way to optimize this, unless you precompute the number of 'a's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exactly five a's, you want to check that there are 5 and not 6:

```
WHERE stadt.Name LIKE '%a%a%a%a%a%' AND
      stadt.Name NOT LIKE '%a%a%a%a%a%a%'
```

Or, use regular expressions:

```
WHERE stadt.Name REGEXP '^([^a]*a[^a]*){5}$'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is exactly what was requested